# Using PHP DOM document, to select HTML element by its class and get its text

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I trying to get text from div where class = **'review-text'**, by using PHP's DOM element with following HTML (same structure) and following code.

**However this doesn't seem to work**

1. HTML

   ```
   $html = '
       <div class="page-wrapper">
           <section class="page single-review" itemtype="http://schema.org/Review" itemscope="" itemprop="review">
               <article class="review clearfix">
                   <div class="review-content">
                       <div class="review-text" itemprop="reviewBody">
                       Outstanding ... 
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </article>
           </section>
       </div>
   ';
   ```
2. PHP Code

   ```
       $classname = 'review-text';
       $dom = new DOMDocument;
       $dom->loadHTML($html);
       $xpath     = new DOMXPath($dom);
       $results = $xpath->query("//*[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classname ')]");

       if ($results->length > 0) {
           echo $review = $results->item(0)->nodeValue;
       }
   ```

*The XPATH syntax to select element by Class is provided at this [Blog](http://westhoffswelt.de/blog/0036_xpath_to_select_html_by_class.html)*

I have tried many example from StackOverflow, online tutorials, but none seems to work. Am I missing something ?

Comment: `//div[contains(@class, 'review-text')]`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The following XPath query does what you want. Just replace the argument provided to $xpath->query with the following:

```
//div[@class="review-text"]
```

Edit:
For easy development, you can test your own XPath query's online at http://www.xpathtester.com/test.

Edit2:
Tested this code; it worked perfectly.

```
<?php

$html = '
    <div class="page-wrapper">
        <section class="page single-review" itemtype="http://schema.org/Review" itemscope="" itemprop="review">
            <article class="review clearfix">
                <div class="review-content">
                    <div class="review-text" itemprop="reviewBody">
                    Outstanding ... 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </article>
        </section>
    </div>
';

$classname = 'review-text';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$results = $xpath->query("//*[@class='" . $classname . "']");

if ($results->length > 0) {
    echo $review = $results->item(0)->nodeValue;
}

?>
```

Comment: I did try your XPath query, that doesn't seem to work either. Does the problem lie with code syntax before querying the XPath.

Answer (score 7):

Expanding on [Frak Houweling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2517048/frank-houweling) answer, it is also possible to use [DomXpath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) to search within a specific [DomNode](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php). This can be acheived by passing the `contextNode` as a second argument to `DomXpath->query` method:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML ($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath ($dom);

foreach ($xpath->query ("//section[@class='page single-review']") as $section)
{
    // search for sub nodes inside each element
    foreach ($xpath->query (".//div[@class='review-text']", $section) as $review)
    {
        echo $review->nodeValue;
    }
}
```

Note that when searching inside nodes you need to use relative paths by adding a dot `.` at the beginning of the expression:

```
"//div[@class='review-text']" // absolute path, search starts from the root element
".//div[@class='review-text']" // relative path, search starts from the provided contextNode
```