# How to extracting a sub <a> tags and prints them out

Tags: php, html, dom

I trying to extract links from a sub `<a>` tag that is inside a `<div>` element. I have used PHP's DOM to parse HTML explained at this site: [http://htmlparsing.com/php.html] [1]. I also modified the code using a related answer from [[Using PHP DOM document, to select HTML element by its class and get its text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18182857/using-php-dom-document-to-select-html-element-by-its-class-and-get-its-text]) [2] to select elements using class name. Following are HTML structure and PHP code.However,the PHP code does not seems to be working well as it stops printing the links once it reach the 11th elements.

**HTML STRUCTURE:**

```
    <div class="avtar-abt">
    <h3 class="mb6"><a href="testingwebsite.com1"></i></a></h3>
    </div>

  <div class="avtar-abt">
    <h3 class="mb6"><a href="testingwebsite.com2"></i></a></h3>
    </div>

  <div class="avtar-abt">
    <h3 class="mb6"><a href="testingwebsite.com3"></i></a></h3>
    </div>
```

**PHP CODE:**

```
    # Create a DOM parser object
$dom = new DOMDocument();

# Parse the HTML from Google.
# The @ before the method call suppresses any warnings that
# loadHTML might throw because of invalid HTML in the page.
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath ($dom);

$classname = 'mb6';

foreach ($xpath->query("//*[@class='$classname']/a") as $link) {
    echo $link->getAttribute('href');
    echo "<br />";

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to extract links and titles from a .html page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423272/how-to-extract-links-and-titles-from-a-html-page)

Comment: I understand that there are similarities. However, I questions  was concerning the` <a>` tag as a sub element of the root `<div>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use two loops (the first one has a wrong syntax BTW). You can use XPath to get right to the link nodes, by adding `/a` to the search path:

```
foreach ($xpath->query("//*[@class='$classname']/a") as $link) {
    echo $link->getAttribute('href');
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Comment: That has solved it. However, It just keep getting only the first 10 links and it stops the search

Comment: Can you post an HTML string with an 11th link that is not found?