# php - simple html dom get element of class

Tags: php, parsing, dom

I try to get from all `div.traffic_entry` elements the following data `img->src` , `img->alt` and `.traffic_detail`. In this test i try to get bäck only the `.traffic_detail` but i get back 1,5MB of Data.

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
//test data, real data are http://www.radio-siegen.de/service/verkehr/
$html->load('
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="traffic_entry ">
             <img class="traffic_img" src="/images/gfx/verkehr/A45.gif" alt="A45 Gießen Richtung Hagen" />
             <div class="traffic_detail">
                 <b>A45 Gießen Richtung Hagen</b><br>
                 Einfahrt Wetzlar-Ost Bauarbeiten, Einfahrt gesperrt, eine Umleitung ist eingerichtet, bis 28.08.2018 15:30 Uhr
         </div>
    </body>
</html>
');

foreach($html->find('.traffic_detail') as $test){
     var_dump($test);
}
```

I use the `version 1.5 ($Rev: 196 $)`.

In the end my array should look like.

```
array(
   array('img' => '/images/gfx/verkehr/A45.gif',
         'heading' =>'A45 Gießen Richtung Hagen',
         'text' => '<b>A45 Gießen Richtung Hagen</b><br>
                    Einfahrt Wetzlar-Ost Bauarbeiten, Einfahrt gesperrt, eine Umleitung ist eingerichtet, bis 28.08.2018 15:30 Uhr'
        ),
   array('img' => '/images/gfx/verkehr/A4.gif',
         'heading' =>'A45 Olpe Richtung Köln',
         'text' => '<b>Agjsdkhklndsl</b><br>
                    klsfdnjknfklnsdjkr'
        )
)
```

Comment: It appears as though you are not closing your `<div class="traffic_detail">`

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18182857/using-php-dom-document-to-select-html-element-by-its-class-and-get-its-text) thread for help