# get HTML element by title value in php

Tags: php

I want to capture the data with the title "Groom Name" in Label, that is, I want to print the "printyazdırasd" output on the screen. How can I get the value inside the label according to the title? With the code below, I print the title of the label on the screen. In other words, I have printed "Damat Adi" on the screen. I want to print the text. I want to print the text according to the title.

**HTML TAG**

```
<label .... title="Damat Adi">yazdıryazdırasd</label>
```

**PHP**

```
 $sql = "SELECT html_kod from  ...";
        $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );

    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
        $paketKFIYAT = $row['html_kod'];
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->loadHTML($paketKFIYAT);
        $iFrame = $dom->getElementsByTagName('label')->item(0);
        $src = $iFrame->getAttribute('title');
        $results = Array("tag" => $src);
        echo json_encode($results);
        }
```

Comment: Why not use PDO instead of the low-level SQL Server driver?

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files.

Comment: How do I do this when I use PDO? I want to print the title, the name of the groom, on the screen. @tadman

Comment: PDO is just a lot friendlier to use, but it also works with other SQL databases so your learning has broader applicability. I mention a framework because this is a solved problem, you don't need to invent your own methods here.

Comment: Can you construct a CSS selector for the element you want? If so you can fetch it by a selector.

Comment: Can you share working code that triggers your problem, along with your debugging attempts? There is nothing like "Groom name" in the given code, neither is there anything like "printyazdırasd"

Comment: I want to give the text according to the title among the html tags. So I want to print the text with the label title "Damat Adı" on the screen @NicoHaase

Comment: I want to shoot the text in this tag in php. @tadman

Comment: You can [select it by xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18182857/using-php-dom-document-to-select-html-element-by-its-class-and-get-its-text).

Comment: thank you, it's work @tadman

Comment: You'll want to post a self-answer with your working code. That will not only help others, but perhaps solidify what you've learned.

Comment: Thank you, much much @tadman

Answer (score 1):

I have captured the data with the title "Groom Name", I get the output of such text to design.

```
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {

    $paketKFIYAT = $row['html_kod'];


    $classname = 'Damat Adi';
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($paketKFIYAT);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $results = $xpath->query("//*[@title='" . $classname . "']");

    if ($results->length > 0) {
        echo $review = $results->item(0)->nodeValue;
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't forget you can interpolate in PHP strings, so `"//*[@title='$classname']"` is sufficient. No need for superfluous concatenation.